# Hadoop map tasks stuck at 100 %

Tags: cloudera-cdh

I use cloudera's distribution for hadoop for running map reduce jobs in a multi peta byte cluster. I see some of maps get stuck at 100%. They show up as 100% but continue running. After a lot of delay,they succeed finally but it takes a lot of time, like some times they take a couple of hours from the time when they show up as 100%.

Answer (score 3):

The map progress percentage is calculated based on the input read. So, if you're doing a lot of work in your mapper after reading the data , or reading ahead of what you've processed, you'll see this more frequently.